# How to access <input type=file> contents?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cappuccino

I have two forms named form1,form2. One form with textfields, another with file inputs. I need to forge a POST request to the serverside with contents of textfields and file inputs. Reading contents of textfields is easy. But I cannot find out how to read file input contents and how to forge POST request with file inputs.

Does anybody know, is it possible?

Comment: What is your server side platform? Java/PHP/Ruby/Perl....?

Comment: I suggest you add the text fields to the form that has the file upload and send them along. You do not want to try to read the user's file system. Browsers do not approve of you trying to access the file upload content

Comment: Can you use one form instead?

Comment: @lobster1234 PHP script. Does that matter?

Comment: @Paul No, I can't. I use Cappuccino framework for interface. Cappuccino put each input field into a separate form.

Comment: @mplungjan I can't. See my comment above.

Comment: @Sergey: ah. That’s unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be doing this via an xmlHttpRequest (Ajax) you need to declare the header as `multipart/form-data`. I believe it would look something like this if you already have a request in the variable `xmlhttp`.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "file.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
xmlhttp.send(queryString());
```

In this example you would build the query string with paired values in the function queryString() so that the output of the function looks like `name=value&name2=value2`. I'm not positive but it shouldn't matter that you're sending file data. I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong on that but you can at least try this.

Comment: After reading some of the comments on your question I realized I may have assumed that you were using PHP (and Ajax) so disregard this if that guess was wrong.

Comment: I know how to use Ajax. I need to know how to access contents of file inputs.

Comment: `document.forms["formname"]["inputname"].value`? Is it not the same code as any other input type? Perhaps this page will help. Edit: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to send the file using `XMLHttpRequest`? If so, you will need to use `XMLHttpRequest2`, the second version of `XMLHttpRequest`, which now supports uploading binary files from the user's computer. 
There's a guide at [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) about it.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Which browsers do support XMLHttpRequest2 ?

Comment: @Sergey I believe the latest versions of Gecko (Firefox) and WebKit (Safari/Chrome) support it. From what I've heard, iOS 5 might, too.